# How to redirect stdin to System.in in a gradle test?

Tags: java, gradle

I have an app which uses `java.util.Scanner` for input from `System.in` using `gradle run`, I can give direct input to the Scanner without exceptions. Normally, I would be getting a `NoSuchElementException` whenever I tried using `./gradlew run`. I then realized I needed to include

```
run {
    standardInput = System.in
}
```

In my `build.gradle`.

I now created a test case which runs the method. `./gradlew test` throws a `NoSuchElementException`. Including

```
test {
    standardInput = System.in
}
```

In my `build.gradle` (which I was suggested to do) also didn't work. Is there something I am doing wrong, or is this just not possible?

Comment: The task class [`Test`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html) does not provide methods for getting or setting `standardInput` or `standardOutput`. Those are only available to all task types derived from [`AbstractExecTask`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/AbstractExecTask.html), e.g. `Exec`.

Comment: So does that mean this can't be done @lu.koerfer?